# Qualification Requirement of Aircraft taxi and landing lights?

Tags: landing, military, dgca-india-regulations

Can anyone provide any standard through which taxi and landing lights are certified for use on aircraft?

And which certification is required for military aircraft lighting systems?

Comment: What country are you asking about?

Comment: for Indian aircrafts

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of any lighting regulations in the [DGCA schedules](http://dgca.nic.in/airrule/parts/Schedules.pdf) however you should take a look at **[PART VI - AIRWORTHINESS](http://dgca.nic.in/part6.htm)** as it will depend a bit on if the aircraft is Indian made or foreign built. From my reading of it if the aircraft is Indian built there is no regulation covering it but if the aircraft is foreign built, in order to receive and airworthy certificate you will need to cary over the foreign airworthy info. This may in turn mean that the light must adhere to the regulations of the certifying body of the aircraft such that the airworthiness can be carried over.  The actual usage of the light does not seem to be regulated under DGCA regulations.